# Breeze Predicate not working when querying serverside

Tags: breeze, server-side, entitymanager, predicate, hottowel

I have a breeze query that ignore the predicate when query from the server. All the data is returned. After that, if I include the same predicate and query locally, the predicates are applied. Is this normal?
my predicate and query looks like

> var predicate = breeze.Predicate("active", "==", false)
>   var query = new EntityQuery("Todos").where(predicate);

The URL sent to the server looks like `http://localhost:8888/Items/GetItems?$filter=active%20eq%20false`

and the method looks like

```
[HttpGet]
public IQuerable<Items> GetItems() {
   return contextprovider.context.Items();
}
```

Is it possible to filter directly from the server and not having to load all and filter locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the `[BreezeController]`tag on my controller.

Answer (score 1):

This IS filtering directly on the server.  The 'active = false' clause is merged into the server side IQueryable before it gets executed against your server side datastore. So as long as the datastore understands how to process an IQueryable ( as EF does) all of the filtering is occurring on the server within the context of the 'combined' query. All you are really doing is passing filter conditions to the server that the server will execute in conjunction with the named endpoint. So the query that is executing on the server is actually

```
contextProvider.context.Items().Where(item => item.active = false);
```

Alternatively you can always avoid 'passing' in the filter conditions by simply changing your server endpoint implementation to perform the filtering explicitly i.e.

```
[HttpGet]
public IQuerable<Items> GetItems() {
   return contextprovider.context.Items().Where(item => item.active = false);
}
```

In both cases exactly the same query will be executed.